# How to use GPU acceleration on Docker without DirectX on Windows Containers

Tags: windows, virtualization, docker, hyper-v, cuda

Microsoft documents that GPU acceleration can be enabled on frameworks built on top of DirectX [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/gpu-acceleration)

NVidia's base Docker image for CUDA is Linux based [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA)

Question: How to enable GPU acceleration on Windows Containers on Docker that aren't based on DirectX ? Say for CUDA or NVidia based systems?

**NOTE:** The goal is to run AI/Neural Network code on a Windows container in Docker

Comment: Docker supporting CUDA (on Windows) would be something that the dockers would have to provide.  All the Microsoft documentation indicates is that you can GPU accelerate a docker contain with DX.

Comment: @Ramhound "the dockers", do you mean Docker employees or the Windows docker container. If you meant the latter, then how does one go about doing that, and making sure that the host system is passing along its GPU resources to the Windows container outside of DX to run Caffe, pytorch or Tensorflow?

Comment: Grammatical mistake.  The comment was supposed to be “Docker developers”.